# What grammar is used in A:"I am happy for you. B:"Are you?"

Tags: grammar

I have found some sentences from an English book, for which I can't find any grammar.

Example 1:

A says:

> I am very happy for you.

B says:

> Are you (or you are)?

Example 2:

A says:

> I like this book.

B says:

> Do you?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. Can you explain which part of the included text you are having difficulty understanding?

Comment: @JoshThomas The example which I have written got it from an English book, my question is that what kind of grammar is used here, what do you we call this kind of structure

Comment: Regardless of the syntax, such questions can be considered rude. It's like saying "Really?" — it's as if B doesn't believe A is sincere.

Comment: Is your question about what A says or what B says? A's grammar is very simple.

Comment: The responses from B are called _echo questions_ (these are deleted forms, of eg _You're very happy for me?_). [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-echo-and-checking-questions) gives examples.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the book was illustrating the fact that English reverses the subject-verb order in a complete question.  So if A says "I am happy for you" (subject "I" followed by verb "am") and B wishes to question the assertion or ask for a clarification, he says, "Are you happy for me? (verb "are" followed by subject "you").

Unfortunately, in abbreviated communication like conversation, B may use either order, "You are?" or "Are you?"

Grammar can take you only so far, and it will be necessary to pay attention to the context and tone to get the full meaning.  I'll give two examples.

```
A: I'm taking that job in China.
B: I'm happy for you.
A: Are you?  [Oh, good! I thought you would object.]

A: I just got a promotion.
B: I'm happy for you.
A: You *are*? [I don't believe you.  You've always been jealous of me.]
```

The bracketed statements, which may be left unstated, give different connotations to the two-word questions.  The first, pleased surprise; the second, skepticism

Comment: That reversal is usually called _inversion_.

Comment: @deadrat Thanks from you explanation, now is good practice to use it in daily conversation or it is not.

Comment: @Yusufahmad I've tried to address your comment in an expansion to my original answer.  I'm not an English teacher, so my recommendations don't carry much weight, but if possible, I'd listen to how native speakers use the construct.